# Running Chromium with yocto

Tags: chromium, yocto, imx6, wayland

I have a imx6 SOM and i am using yocto (krogoth). I want to install the chromium browser and so I added the following to the conf and the chromium is now build.

```
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += "chromium libexif weston"
PNBLACKLIST[chromium] = ""
```

When i want to start the browser i always got the following messages:

```
var-som-mx6 /mnt/user# ./chrome.sh www.google.com
[1157:1157:0805/150113:ERROR:display.cc(148)] WaylandDisplay failed to     initialize hardware
[1157:1157:0805/150113:FATAL:ozone_platform_wayland.cc(115)] failed to initialize display hardware
#0 0x0000551dd27a <unknown>
#1 0x0000551ec9fe <unknown>
#2 0x0000558339fa <unknown>
#3 0x000055918254 <unknown>
#4 0x000055918ba4 <unknown>
#5 0x000055918c82 <unknown>
#6 0x0000578341ac <unknown>
#7 0x0000551ae960 <unknown>
#8 0x0000551ae1ba <unknown>
#9 0x000054edd5c0 ChromeMain
#10 0x0000764e1cf8 __libc_start_main

Received signal 6
#0 0x0000551dd27a <unknown>
#1 0x0000551dd548 <unknown>
#2 0x0000764f7b40 <unknown>
#3 0x0000764f6910 gsignal
[end of stack trace]
./chrome.sh: line 15:  1129 Segmentation fault      /usr/bin/chromium/chrome ${CHROME_EXTRA_ARGS} $@
```

The script chrome.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

export HOME=/tmp/
export CHROME_DEVEL_SANDBOX=/usr/sbin/chrome-devel-sandbox
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/chromium
export GOOGLE_API_KEY="no"
export GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_ID="no"
export GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_SECRET="no"

CHROME_EXTRA_ARGS=" --use-gl=egl --gpu-no-context-lost --start-fullscreen --kiosk --no-first-run --ignore-gpu-blacklist --user-data-dir=/tmp/.chromium/"
CHROME_EXTRA_ARGS="${CHROME_EXTRA_ARGS} --disable-pinch --disable-touch-adjustment --enable-touch-drag-drop --touch-events=enabled"

/usr/bin/chromium/chrome ${CHROME_EXTRA_ARGS} $@
```

Dows anyone gives me an advise what is wrong or what i can try?! Thanks.

BR Harald

Comment: It seems that chrome isn't able to render on diplay. Try export DISPLAY:=0 and then try to run chrome.sh

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your advise. I added export DISPLAY=0 but it make no difference. To you have any other idea?

Comment: I also tested export DISPLAY=:0 but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Note that krogoth is very old, so I do not think anyone can give you specific advice anymore about what is wrong. You should try a recent version of Yocto, or even the master branch.